# Best practice for generating Cake-style URLs from Cake-generated dropdown form

Tags: cakephp, html-select

This seems less obvious than it ought to be. I've got a simple CakePhp select form, with a dropdown list whose options were generated by Cake's 'list' style find operation. By default the form sends data via post, so I set the type to 'get' as I want the URL to appear and be suitable for bookmarking etc.

So the default format for that turns out to be a query string, e.g., **sitename/controller/action?id=3**

As opposed to the Cake-style: **sitename/controller/action/3** -- which I'd have expected Cake to use as a default, but I'm sure there are good reasons for their choice there.

I wanted that second, Cake-style URL, so I put in a beforeFilter that looks for the query string and uses it to build the URL I prefer, and then redirects to it.

This works fine but I can't shake the vague feeling I'm doing this the stupid way. Is there a more built-in behavior that I have managed not to discover?

Thanks for any advice. And oh: I am still using CakePhp 2.x.

Comment: You are trying to form an idempotent list (order not relevant) to an ordered list. That in itself contains issues. You most likely will have to manually address those in a sane manner, making sure you also include required in front of optional arguments.

Comment: At the risk of demonstrating I have no idea what your comment means, all I'm trying to do is make a select/dropdown list that, when you choose an item, takes you to a URL in the format sitename/controller/action/integer. I could manually code this very easily but I'm using CakePhp (2.x) and I'd like to do it the Cake way. The default 'get' behavior of a CakePhp form employs a query string rather than the slash-delimited URL I'm after. Forgive me if I don't see the relevance of ordered lists or the exciting word 'idempotent'.

Comment: Oh, so you only care about a count of query string elements === 1. That sure makes things easier. But here just could use PRG pattern and reformat target URL in post case. Or you use custom JS to redirect to your URL of choice upon selection in the dropdown.

Comment: If there aren't many such actions that you want to handle this, why not build the action so that it can find the parameter in either place?